# JTcalendar - How to use the method (BOOL)haveTaskForDay:(NSDate*)date

Tags: ios, objective-c, jtcalendar

I'm using `JTCalendar` in my project. I've to show `indicators (round dots)` under dates if an event for that day is available. Response from the API gives me an `array of dictionaries`. Dictionary has a key `"service_date"` and value in string like `"10/02/2017"`.

How can i use the method `haveTaskForDay` to check service dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JTCalendar's delegate:

```
- (void)calendar:(JTCalendarManager *)calendar prepareDayView:(JTCalendarDayView *)dayView
{

            if([self haveTaskForDay:dayView.date])
            {
                dayView.dotView.hidden = NO;
                dayView.dotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            }
            else
            {
                dayView.dotView.hidden = YES;
            }
}
```

and in your `haveTaskForDay` method, you will get date parameter from above delegate then you can check if date is similar with the one in your dictionary:

```
- (BOOL) haveTaskForDay :(NSDate *)date
{
 for (NSDictionary * eventDictionary in yourArray)
        {
            NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
            NSString * calendarDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];

            NSString * dateString = [eventDictionary objectForKey : @"service_date"];

            if([dateString isEqualToString:calendarDate])
                return 1;
        }

    }
        return 0;
}
```

Note: I did not run this code. You should make corrections if necessary.

Comment: "and in your `haveTaskForDay` method, you will get date parameter from above delegate then you can check if date is similar with the one in your dictionary." - actually this is the thing which is not working...

Comment: I tried this method. and it is working. but JTCalendar is not showing dots as the view loads. only if user interacts with it by tapping any date, the dots are visible.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i just had to reload `_calendarManager` after the api response. Thanks for help.

Comment: Welcome  mate :)